# How to find why sum of all subsets of data is 1 less than total

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I have some award data. Each award or grant has a grant number and amount and the ID of the entity. I summarize the Count of the awards and the $Amount of all awards by ID. Then I return either a total set of rows or a subset based on a range check.

How can I find out why the sum of all subsets is always one less than the total set? Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER    Procedure [dbo].[FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards]
/* 
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 0
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 1
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 2
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 3
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 4
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 5
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 6
*/
-- populates #TempGrants according to range filter on TotalAmount
(
    @Range  int = 0
                    -- 0 = no filtering 
                    -- 1 = < $1 million
                    -- 2 = < $5 million
                    -- 3 = < $10 million
                    -- 4 = < $15 million
                    -- 5 = < $20 million
                    -- 6 = > $20 million
)
As
-- if calling sproc did not create this table, create here to allow unit testing
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempGrants') IS NULL
BEGIN 
CREATE TABLE #TempGrants
(
    ID          nchar(6) NOT NULL
,   TotalAwards decimal (16, 0) NULL
,   TotalAmount decimal (16, 0) NULL
)
END
-- step 1. Summarize grants creating colums for HAVING filter
CREATE TABLE #TempGrantsUnfiltered
(
    ID          nchar(6) NOT NULL
,   TotalAwards decimal (16, 0) NULL
,   TotalAmount decimal (16, 0) NULL
)
insert into #TempGrantsUnfiltered
(
    ID          
,   TotalAwards 
,   TotalAmount 
)
select o.id
      ,COUNT( o.GrantNumber) as TotalAwards
      ,SUM( o.TotalObligatedAmount) as TotalAmount 
from dbo.FLAS2_Grants o
group BY O.ID
-- step 2. HAVING filter returns grant totals per range test
insert into #TempGrants
(
    ID          
,   TotalAwards 
,   TotalAmount 
)
select o.id
      ,TotalAwards
      ,TotalAmount 
from #TempGrantsUnfiltered o
WHERE
    CASE 
        When @Range = 0 Then 1  
        When @Range = 1 AND TotalAmount < 1000000 Then 1  
        When @Range = 2 AND TotalAmount BETWEEN  1000001  AND  5000000 Then 1  
        When @Range = 3 AND TotalAmount BETWEEN  5000001  AND 10000000 Then 1  
        When @Range = 4 AND TotalAmount BETWEEN 10000001  AND 15000000 Then 1  
        When @Range = 5 AND TotalAmount BETWEEN 15000001  AND 20000000 Then 1  
        When @Range = 6 AND TotalAmount > 20000000 Then 1  
        ELSE 0      -- where 0 = 1 rejects record
        END = 1     -- where 1 = 1 allows record
order by TotalAmount desc
```

When I execute the following block:

```
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 0
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 1
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 2
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 3
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 4
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 5
EXECUTE FLAS2_List_Awards_V3_PrepAwards 6
```

I get the following results in my Messages window using SQL Management Studio:

```
(597 row(s) affected)

(597 row(s) affected)

(597 row(s) affected)

(65 row(s) affected)

(597 row(s) affected)

(341 row(s) affected)

(597 row(s) affected)

(89 row(s) affected)

(597 row(s) affected)

(39 row(s) affected)

(597 row(s) affected)

(23 row(s) affected)

(597 row(s) affected)

(39 row(s) affected)
```

I cannot account for the missing row in the subset(s) or the extra row in the total set. Any ideas?

```
65 + 341 + 89 + 39 + 23 +39 = 596 < 597
```

Comment: Shouldn't `TotalAmount < 1000000` be `TotalAmount <= 1000000` or `TotalAmount < 1000001` instead?

Comment: I agree with SqlZim - if you have an award where the TotalAmount = 1000000 then this isn't going to get picked up by any of the filters but it will get picked up by the unfiltered total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `TotalAmount < 1000000` to `TotalAmount < 1000001` in your `case` expression.

Comment: Thanks very much! I suspected some dumb mistake but just couldn't see it.

Comment: Just be careful - I see this all the time. People don't clearly specify what they want to happen at the boundaries of ranges. The comments in your stored procedure say things like @Range = 2 filters for TotalAmount < $5 million, however your case statement will filter for TotalAmount <= $5million. Which do you want?